# How to store image in node backend?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, backend

I am using node and express for backend and Mongo DB for storage.I am using multer middleware for storing image,i got a problem and the problem is when i store an image from local host it get saved in my backend and also shown in database,but when i deploy the same api on heroku or any other app the image is shown in database but it is not stored in my backend.I have tested the code on postman,what may be the issue?

Following below is my code on node js:

```
router.use(express.static(__dirname + 'public'));

let storage = multer.diskStorage({
destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, 'public')
},
filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname))
}
})

let upload = multer({ storage: storage })
router.post('/fellows-details', upload.single('image'), async (req, res) => {

const { error } = FellowsDetails(req.body);
if (error) return res.status(400).send({ message: error.details[0].message });
const fellow = new fellowdetails({
    name: req.body.name,
    details: req.body.details,
    image: req.file.filename
})
try {
    fellow.save()
    res.status(200).send({ message: 'fellows detail saved successfully' })
} catch (err) {
    res.status(400).send(err);
}
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will become easy to store files after converting in string
you just have to convert string in image in your frontend

convert image in to `base64` string using this code in your api and also don't forgot to delete file from upload folder

`"img": new Buffer.from(fs.readFileSync(req.file.path)).toString("base64")`

to delete the file

```
           let resultHandler = function (err) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log("unlink failed", err);
                } else {
                    console.log("file deleted");
                }
            }

            fs.unlink(req.file.path, resultHandler);
```

at your routes import `multer`

```
 `multer const multer = require('multer');
  const upload = multer({ dest: __dirname + '/uploads/images' });`
```

Add `upload.single('img')` in your request

```
router.post('/fellows-details', authorize([Role.ADMIN, Role.USER]), 
            upload.single('img'), usersController.fellowsdetails);
```

Answer (score 0):

The filesystem on Heroku is not suitable for the persistent storage of data. The Heroku filesystem is ephemeral - that means that any changes to the filesystem whilst the dyno is running only last until that dyno is shut down or restarted. Each dyno boots with a clean copy of the filesystem from the most recent deploy
You can't store files on Heroku. Heroku automatically removed your uploaded files. You have to use external services like Amazon S3 or Azure Blob Storage.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/s3-node-examples.html
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/storage-blob/blockblobclient?view=azure-node-latest

If you don't want to set up an account with AWS to create an S3 bucket we also have add-ons here that handle storage and processing of static assets https://elements.heroku.com/addons

Answer (score -1):

var dateString = Date.now();
var storage = multer.diskStorage({

```
destination: (req, file, cb) => {
cb(null, './uploads/')


 },


filename: (req, file, cb) => {
cb(null,  dateString+'_'+file.originalname)


}
});



var maxSize=3  1000  1000;


var upload = multer({ storage: storage,
limits: { fileSize: maxSize }})

var upload = multer({ storage: storage , limits: { fileSize: maxSize }});
app.post("/fileupload", upload.single("fileToUpload"), function (req, res) {


console.log(req.file.originalname)
var uploaded =  "http://localhost:4001/"+dateString+'_'+req.file.originalname;
console.log(uploaded)
res.json({status: 200,msg:'File saved successfully',data:uploaded});
});
```

Comment: The problem is with Heroku. Heroku not allow storing files uploaded by the user.