# Deleting Multer uploads object after processing Express

Tags: node.js, express, multer

I am trying to delete the file object that is created and stored in the `uploads folder`.

Here is my config options for multer:

const path = require('path')

```
multerConfigOpt = {
    dest: 'uploads/',
    fileFilter:  function(req, file, cb) {
        var ext = path.extname(file.originalname)
        console.log(ext);
        if (ext === '.pdf' || ext === '.doc' || ext === '.docx' || ext === '.txt') {
            console.log("true!");
            cb(null,true)
        } else {
            cb(null, false)
        }
    }
}

module.exports = multerConfigOpt
```

After processing the files that was submitted by a user via a HTML Form I would like to delete it. When I try and do the following:

```
    await fs.unlink(this.file.path, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    })
```

However I get the following error:

```
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted,
```

these files that are store in the uploads folder do not have an extension. I believe they are just binary files that were created by multer.

Below is an example of the file that is in the uploads folder path.

[image]

All I do with the file is send it as an attachment through email using nodemailer

```
if (this.file && this.isJobSeeker) {
    mailOptions.attachments = [{
        filename: 'resume.pdf',
        content:  fs.createReadStream(this.file.path)
    }]
}
```

How can I delete these files?

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Does "processing" your file invoive reading the files into memory?

Comment: @AnujPancholi I've updated my previous question to show how i handle the processing

Comment: Can you check what  `this.file.path` is? Seems like folder rather than file. And hence the `EPERM` error. Or `fs.unlink` couldn't find this file.

Comment: I think you could find solution on this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/63895045/12761193

Answer (score 1):

The [createReadStream function in fs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createreadstream_path_options) also may take a buffer as an input, however, it seems that `fs.createReadStream()` converts that buffer to a string which ultimately must contain a file path (which seems like an important detail they should've mentioned in the docs).

Multer has a feature where instead of storing the file on your disk, [you can have the file as an in-memory buffer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer#memorystorage).

You may try:

```
const multerMemoryStorage = multer.memoryStorage();

multerConfigOpt = {
    storage: multerMemoryStorage,
    fileFilter:  function(req, file, cb) {
        var ext = path.extname(file.originalname)
        console.log(ext);
        if (ext === '.pdf' || ext === '.doc' || ext === '.docx' || ext === '.txt') {
            console.log("true!");
            cb(null,true)
        } else {
            cb(null, false)
        }
    }
}
```

Then, if you're taking `req.file` in `this.file` in your processing function, you can do the following:

Using the [stream module](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v12.x/docs/api/stream.html#stream_stream) in nodejs, we can convert the buffer into a [readable](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v12.x/docs/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_readable) stream, which is the base class of `fs.ReadStream`.

```
const stream = require('stream')
const getNewReadableStreamFromBuffer = (inputBuffer) => {
    const readable = new stream.Readable.from(inputBuffer);
    

    return readable;
}
if (this.file && this.isJobSeeker) {
    mailOptions.attachments = [{
        filename: 'resume.pdf',
        content: getNewReadableStreamFromBuffer(this.file.buffer)
    }]
}
```

The file need not be deleted, because it's never saved to disk. And since nodejs is garbage collected, the buffer should be cleared from memory.

**NOTE:** Multer docs mention in a warning that in this approach, you must ensure that your server has enough memory to keep in-memory buffers of uploaded files, as some files may be quite large. If your files are small enough, it will work smoothly.

Comment: I've tried your suggestion. However when i use the `fs.createReadStream(this.file.buffer) ` i get a error `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_VALUE]: The argument 'path' must be a string or Uint8Array without null bytes. Received <Buffer 
25 50 44 46 2d 31 2e 37 0d 0a 25 b5 b5 b5`

Comment: I was misled by nodejs docs, however, I've edited my answer with a fix.