# Cannot upload file from React to Express with Multer (req.file don`t show anything,req.body is ok)

Tags: javascript, express, sequelize.js, multer

**I have a problem for a few days how to send the file through reactjs to express and store it in mysql via sequelizing ORM. I use two separate folders arhiva-backend and arhiva-frontend which are connected by CORS. I manage to send via formData and insert everything from req.body into the database, but req.file doesn't work at all. Please help.**

This is my reactjs file. I`m using ExpressJs, React the newest version, Sequelize ORM, phpmyadmin (mysql) for storring data.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import DashboardSideBar from '../components/DashboardSideBar';
import DashboardHeader from '../components/DashboardHeader';
import CreateDosijeForm from '../components/forms/CreateDosijeForm';
// import axios from 'axios';

class CreateWorkerDosije extends Component{

constructor (props){
    super (props);

    this.state = {
        data:{
            firstName:'',
            lastName:'',
            dosijeNum:'',
            jmbg:'',
            uploadedFile:'',

            },


    }
    this.changeData = this.changeData.bind(this);
    this.onSubmitData = this.onSubmitData.bind(this);
}

changeData(e) {
    switch(e.uploadedFile){
        case "uploadedFile":
            this.setState({ uploadedFile: e.target.files[0] });
            break;
            default:
     
    const field = e.target.name;
    const data = this.state.data;
    data[field] = e.target.value;

    this.setState({
        data
    });

}
}

onSubmitData = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    // const data = this.state.data;
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('uploadedFile',this.state.uploadedFile);
    formData.append('firstName', this.state.data.firstName);
    formData.append('lastName', this.state.data.lastName);
    formData.append('dosijeNum', this.state.data.dosijeNum);
    formData.append('jmbg', this.state.data.jmbg);
    fetch("http://localhost:5000/api/upload",{
        method:"POST",
        body:(
            formData
        ),
      })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .catch((error )=> {
          console.log(error)
      });
    

        
}



render() {
    return(
        
            <div id = "create-dosije-form">
                <DashboardSideBar/>
                    <div className="dashboard-body">
                        <DashboardHeader/>

                    </div>

                <div className="dashboard-content">
                        <div className="headline filter primary">
                                <h4> Unesi novi dosije </h4>
                        </div>
                        
                
                <CreateDosijeForm
                data = {this.state.data}
                onChange = {this.changeData}
                onSubmit = {this.onSubmitData}
                />
                </div>



            </div>
            
        
    )
}


}

export default CreateWorkerDosije;
```

This is form

```
import React from 'react';


const CreateDosijeForm = ({

                                 onSubmit,
                                 onChange,
                                 data

                             }) => (
    <div>
        <form id="departman-form" onSubmit = {onSubmit} encType = "multipart/form-data">
            <label htmlFor="firstName" className="rl-label required">Ime</label>
            <input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName" value = {data.firstName} placeholder="Unesite ime radnika"  onChange={onChange}/><br/>
            <label htmlFor="lastName" className="rl-label required">Prezime</label>
            <input type="text" id="lastName" name="lastName" value = {data.lastName} placeholder="Unesite ime radnika"  onChange={onChange}/><br/>
            <label htmlFor="dosijenum" className="rl-label required" >Broj dosijea</label><br/>
            <input type="text" pattern = "[0-9]*" id="dosijenum" name="dosijeNum" value = {data.dosijeNum} placeholder="Unesite broj dosijea" onChange={onChange}/><br/>
      
            <label htmlFor="jmbg" className="rl-label required">JMBG/PIO/LBO</label><br/>
            <input type="number" id="jmbg" name="jmbg" value = {data.jmbg} placeholder="Unesite JMBG/PIO/LBO broj radnika" onChange={onChange}/><br/>
            <label htmlFor="file" className="rl-label required">Izaberite fajlove</label><br/>
            <input type="file" id="uploaded_file" name="uploadedFile" value = {data.uploadedFile} placeholder="Unesite dokumenta" multiple/><br/>

            <button className="button mid dark">Sačuvaj</button>
            <p className="rl-label required">Polja oznacena sa zvezdicom su obavezna polja</p>                        
        </form>



    </div>
);

export default CreateDosijeForm;
```

EXPRESS CODE

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const multer = require('multer');
const cors = require('cors')
// const router = express.Router();

const app = express();
// console.log(port)

const sequelize = require ('./config/database');
const Dosije = require('./models/dosije');

let corsOptions = {
    origin: "http://localhost:5000"
}

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
app.use((req,res,next)=>{
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type', 'Authorization');
    next();
})


sequelize.sync().then(result => {
    // console.log(result)
    try {
        sequelize.authenticate();
        console.log('Connection has been established successfully.');
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', error);
      }
});

//Set Storage engine
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function(req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, './public/uploads/')
    },
    filename: function(req,file,cb) {
        cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + Path2D.extname(file.originalname));
    }
});

  //init upload

const upload = multer({storage});



app.post('/api/upload', upload.single('uploadedFile'), (req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.file)
    console.log(req.body)    
    const file = (req.file)

    if (!file) {
    const error = new Error('Please upload a file')
    return next(error)
  }
    

    const firstName = req.body.firstName;
    const lastName = req.body.lastName;
    const dosijeNum = req.body.dosijeNum;
    const jmbg = req.body.jmbg;
    const uploadedFile = req.file
    Dosije.create({ 
        dosijeNum: dosijeNum,
        firstName: firstName,
        lastName: lastName,
        JMBG: jmbg,
        docs: uploadedFile
    })
    .then(res=>{
        console.log(res)})
        .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    })
    res.send();
    next();

    
    })
    
    

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server listening on port ${port}`));
```

MODEL

```
const Sequelize = require ('sequelize');

const sequelize = require ('../config/database');
const Dosije = sequelize.define('dosije', {
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    dosijeNum:{
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
    },
    firstName:{
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        
    },
    lastName: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
    },
    JMBG: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        
    },
    docs: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
    },
    
});

module.exports = Dosije;
```

Comment: What's does `console.log(req.file) says ?

Comment: check out this thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/63895045/12761193

Comment: console.log(req.file) says undefined @AvivLo

Answer (score 0):

**Frontend:**

Change this:

```html
<input type="file" id="uploaded_file" name="uploadedFile" value = {data.uploadedFile} placeholder="Unesite dokumenta" multiple/><br/>
```

To this:

```html
<input type="file" name="file">
```

**Backend:**
Change this:

```html
upload.single('uploadedFile')
```

To this:

```
upload.single('file')
```

Comment: ok man, i`m getting something.... in express req.body i`m get ...   undefined
[Object: null prototype] {
  uploadedFile: 'C:\\fakepath\\1570104140-cenovnik-smestaja.pdf',
  firstName: 'Micko',
  lastName: 'Mickovic',
  dosijeNum: '9874',
  jmbg: '12589'
}  Now I'm confused, why is my req.file shown in req.body console.log, and req.file still tells me that is undefined when i console.log (req.file)

Comment: You gotta change `upload.single('uploadedFile')` to `upload.single('file')`. Just try my code above and make modifications accordingly to see if it works.

Comment: I tried your code, req.file is again undefined, but ... req.body.file i`m getting C: \\ fakepath \\ Hospital Department for program.rtf. I don't know where the problem is now, maybe I'm not sending the data to formData well? @Aviv Lo